# Get and store ALL atributes and values and then re apply them back to same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a plugin that in order to work cross browser, needs to run after the the image its attached to has loaded.

I could use the **new Image()** and then **wait for it to load** and then append it etc.

But that means **re setting all the attributes** s which doesn't seem feasible as some of the plugin options can be stored on data attributes which makes it hard to keep track of them all..

If there is a better way please share :)

I basically just need to instantiate my plugin after the image it attached is loaded :)

please don't suggest

`$('img').load(function(){//do something});`

as it doesn't work consistently. :)

Cheers.

Comment: `img.load` *should* work consistently insofar as meaning "after the image is available for rendering". Exactly how does it work inconsistently?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your plugin on $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() that would run the plugin afte everything on the page has loaded.

Like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Initialize Plugin
});
```

The only caveat is that this would only work if all the images the plugin is using are already in the DOM.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Jamesthompson A very good point; you may consider having the plugin auto initialize whereby you can control which event the plugin uses or include instructions in your documentation for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save state between browsers or sessions I think this is not possible right now with javascript; however, it is coming really soon.

I may be wrong but I believe you're going to have to pack and unpack your data into the localstorage.

Try using  localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

Can you use document ready?

Wrap your plugin inside the document ready for jQuery.

```
$(function () {

            //wrapp plugin



})
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm trying to do something that can be achieved another way. I just need the plugin to run after the image has loaded.

Comment: Oh yea, that is way different than what was asked.